# Use Yii2 REST client to consume Yii2 REST API

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2, rest-client

I have created a REST API using the [Yii2 documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start). It seems to be working fine as I can use curl like this:

```
curl -i "https://example.com/api/v3/user" \
    -H "Accept:application/json"  \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I would now like to be able to consume this data from another Yii2 site. I am trying to use the Yii2 REST API client. I won't post the whole code as it's basically a copy of the [Facebook client](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/src/clients/Google.php) in [yiisoft/yii2-authclient](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient).

Does anyone know of a guide to help me amend this to comsume my API? In the first instance, I'm struggling with what to put for `$authUrl` and `$tokenUrl`.

Comment: you should go through the documentation to have a knowledge how to build Restful Web Services with Yii2 and especially go through the section [**`Authentication`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication)

Comment: Yup, @MuhammadOmerAslam, thanks. I've already gone through all the tutorials and have a working REST API. Any idea how to consume it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if you need to extend outh2 class as I believe you don't have the authentication logic completed in the first Yii2 webapp, like authenticating using first webapp url then redirect to the second webapp to extract the token from url.

It could be simpler just create a component that have those methods

```
class YourRestClient {
  const BASE_URL = 'https://example.com/api/v3';
  private $_token = null;

  public function authenticate($username,$password){
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->createRequest()
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->setUrl(BASE_URL.'/user/login')
    ->setData(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])
    ->send();
    if ($response->isOk) {
        $this->_token = $response->data['token'];
    }
  }

    public function logout(){
      //your logut logic
    }

    public function refreshToken(){
      //your refresh logic 
    }

    public function userList(){
      $client = new Client();
      $response = $client->createRequest()
      ->setMethod('GET')
      ->setUrl(BASE_URL.'/user/users')
      ->addHeaders([
          'content-type' => 'application/json',
          'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$_token,
      ])
      ->send();
      if ($response->isOk) {
          return $response->getData();
      }
    }
}
```

for more info [httpclient](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient)

Answer (score 2):

If I am not wrong what you will need for this, is to use `yiisoft/yii2-httpclient`
Ref: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient
Add it: `php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-httpclient`

Then make the call «I would probably build a model to handle this»

```
use yii\httpclient\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->createRequest()
    ->setMethod('GET')
    ->setUrl('https://example.com/api/v3/user')
    ->addHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'])
    ->send();
if ($response->isOk) {
    // use your data
}
```